# jQuery ajax post request doesn't work suddenly,

Tags: ajax, jquery, zend-framework2

I have a jQuery ajax call in my ZF2 application. It just worked before. Suddenly it won't work anymore. Even when I put a non-existent action in the request, it doesn't give a server error like it did before. It just seems like it doesn't make the request.

There's absolutely no errors in the console. Everything works up until the point where I make the request. This is the function it's in:

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    var CCID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    CCID = parseInt(CCID);

    console.log(CCID);                                   // Works

    if($.inArray(CCID,$expanded) > -1){
        foldin(CCID);
    } else {
        console.log('Works up to here.');                // Works
        $.post('admin/expand', {
            id: CCID
        },function(data){
            console.log('Doesn\'t log this.');           // Doesn't work
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('info')){     
                console.log('sup');
                expand(data.info);
            } else {
                console.log('Can\'t find customer info.');
            }
        },'json'); 
    }
});
```

Like I said before, absolutely no errors, and logs all the bits that I commented that do. Kind of hoping I made a stupid mistake and you can spot it. Been over it a bunch of times already, can't find it.

I'll add the action in my controller if anyone want to see it, but the post request doesn't even seem to look for it, because it doesn't give an error if I give it a bogus action.

**edit: below is some extra information**

So I added a failure handler at the request of a commenter, it returned:

```
failed [Object, "parseerror", SyntaxError]
```

In SyntaxError it says "unexpected token <", but there's none in the .js file and I can't find where it tells me what line/file it finds it in. That would help, probably.

This is the action I call in my controller. Doesn't seem to find it at all though:

```
public function expandAction(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    if($request->isPost()){ 
        $post_data = $request->getPost();
        $CCID = $post_data['id'];
        $customer = $this->getCustomerTable()->getCustomer($CCID);
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array(
            'info'      => $customer,
        )));    
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Try to add a failure handler and see whether it is getting called `$.post('admin/expand', {..}, function(){}).fail(function(){console.log('failed', arguments)})`

Comment: Can you clarify a few things: 1) "Suddenly it won't work anymore": did it work before, what did you change, what do you mean with "does not work"? 2) What's the request you send (check the inspector in Chrome/Firefox) 3) What's the response you get back, what's the status code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Wow, didn't know that before. That definitely returned something. `falied [Object, "parseerror", SyntaxError]` Is SyntaxError the best place to look? It's a bit big and daunting.

Comment: Try check to your console log in your web browser when you're making the ajax call. It's either ajax call is failed or there is something wrong with the response

Comment: @JurianSluiman, like I said, I read the console in Chrome and it gives exactly *no* response. No errors, only stuff that I logged. That handler Arun mentioned did return something (the above).

Comment: That means the value returned by the server is not a valid json response... can you inspect the value returned by the server using a browser developer tool

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think so. Would I call console.log(data)? Cause that doesn't log anything. I don't think it returns anything at all.

Comment: the best tool in this case is to use firebug for FireFox or developer tools for Chrome and use the network tab in these tools to evaluate the ajax request and the response attributes

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks. Very very helpful. Turns out the path was wrong and it should've been 'expand' instead of 'admin/expand'.

Comment: @vanamerongen by checking request/response I also meant reading the network stuff under the "Network" tab ;) You can read the complete payload, including headers and body. That gives you much more info than just the console.

Answer (score 1):

Arun P Johny taught me to use the Network tab in Google Chrome developer tools to figure out the problem. From there I could see that the path 'admin/expand' should've been 'expand'.

Might be a bit of a localized answer but I feel that his advice to use the network tab was helpful enough to warrant an answer. Maybe it'll be helpful to someone else at some point.